# Merging parent is causing orphandelete

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

i have the two classes / entities ProcJobData and SubstrateData

ProcjobData:

```
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "procJobData", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
private List<SubstrateData> substrateData;
...
```

and SubstrateData:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "procjobdata_fk")
privateProcJobData procJobData();
```

in my code jobmanager i create a new procjobdata and set some values and hold it as a member.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

try {
     em.getTransaction().begin();
     pjData = new ProcJobData();
     ... set some values
     pjData = ProcJobDataDAO.create(em, pjData);
     em.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (Exception ex) {
     LOG.error("Failed to persist ProcJob[" + procJobNo + "]", ex);
     if (em.getTransaction().isActive()) {
           em.getTransaction().rollback();
     }
} finally {
     if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
           em.close();
     }
}
```

then a bit later i add the SubstrateData:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SUBSTRATES; i++){
    ...
    SubstrateData substrate = new SubstrateData();
    ...
    substrate.setProcJobData(this.procJobData);
    SubstrateData create = SubstrateDataDAO.create(em, substrate);
    procJobData.addSubstrateData(create);
}
this.procJobData = em.merge(this.procJobData);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

the create method of the SubstrateDataDAO:

```
public static SubstrateData create(final EntityManager entityManager, final    SubstrateData entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    entityManager.flush();
    return entity;
}
```

now my problem: i always use transactions if i change some values. If i merge the procJobData entity inside an open transaction i will get a new instance of it and all my substrateDatas are orphans cause they still link to the old instance and hibernate will delete the entries. 
i removed the merge inside the transaction and everything is fine - but why??
the question is: do i need the merge inside a transaction?

**EDIT:** also if i will merge the procjobdata entity later - the substrates will still get deleted. like in this code a bit later - at this point there are databank entries for the substrates:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
this.procJobData.setLoadOn(new Date());
this.procJobData = em.merge(this.procJobData); //edit -> using return value
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Show us how you were doing the merge inside a transaction where it gave you problems.

Comment: just before the transaction commit is tried: em.merge(this.procJobData); em.flush();
but also mention my new last sentence.. also when im outside of the transaction and somewhere else in the code i make a merge inside the transaction the substratedatas will get deleted

Answer (score 0):

Your merge code should do this:

```
this.procJobData = em.merge( this.procJobData );
```

The reason is clear from the java documentation

```
Returns: the managed instance that the state was merged to
```

The instance you provide is merely used as a container of data.  You want to make sure you hold a reference to the returned object so that you maintain adequate state in your class of what the persistence provider currently has merged.

Comment: if i want to add more then just one substratdata like 20 how can i do this?
getTransaction().begin();
for 1...20
SubstrateData substrate = new SubstrateData();
...
substrate.setProcJobData(this.procJobData);
endFor

this.procJobData = em.merge(this.procJobData);
em.getTransaction().commit();

is not working.. after merge the list is empty

Comment: Well what little bit you posted, I don't see where you're adding `SubstrateData` to the `ProcjobData` object's list of substrates.  Are you making sure you set both sides of the relationship correctly?

Comment: i changed the code so it looks like mine - in general the question is why to use merge? everything is fine without merge. the problem is, if there will be some merge elsewhere in the code (like in my case some methods later) the list of the substrates are getting deleted